# How to Improve Speed of Image Creation With Matplotlib

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, multiprocessing

I have a numpy array with 4 million samples, each with 4 x 40 data points. and I need to create 4 million charts, each with 4 individual sub plots. I am using matplotlib with the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)
gs.update(left=0, wspace=0)

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax1.plot(data_1, 's')
ax1.axis('off')

ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax2.plot(data_2, 's')
ax2.axis('off')

ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[2])
ax3.plot(data_3, 's')
ax3.axis('off')

ax4 = plt.subplot(gs[3])
ax4.plot(data_4, 's')
ax4.axis('off')

plt.savefig(os.path.join(cwd, 'data/%d.png' % index), bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0, dpi=20)
plt.close()
```

I am running this using Python multiprocessing with 36 processes on a machine with 36 CPU cores. But after 10+ hours of running it has only produced 40k images out of 4 million. Far too slow for my liking. I thought the I/O operations could possibly be a bottleneck but the machine is running on an SSD so it seems unlikely.

Any suggestions to improve this speed?

Comment: Ok, I have to ask. What are you planning to do with *sixteen million* plots?

Comment: I'd like to meet with the guy in charge of looking at these plot...

Comment: Also, something is wrong with your multiprocessing. Doing a quick timing test on my machine suggests that *one* process should be able to do 40K images in a few hours. Are you sure that your processes aren't somehow contesting a shared object? Like a file, lock, etc?

Comment: To find the bottleneck, one would need to see the code doing the multiprocessing. See [mcve]. Otherwise one cannot help here.